# I need the button to update my window, not create new

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a code in which a window with a different form should open by clicking on the button. I want my window not to create a new one by clicking on the button, but to be updated with a different form. Is it possible to do this?

I tried to create a new function that updates the window, but I'm not good at it.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def uskbut():
    uskbut = tk.Toplevel()
    labu1=tk.Label(uskbut, text="Фотоэффект")
    labu1.pack()
    butu1=tk.Button(uskbut, text="Тема")
    butu1.pack(side="left")
    butu2=tk.Button(uskbut, text="Формулы")
    butu2.pack(side="right")

def mehnew():
    mehnew = tk.Toplevel()
    labm=tk.Label(mehnew, text="Квантовая физика")
    butm=tk.Button(mehnew, text="Фотоэффект", command=uskbut)
    labm.pack()
    butm.pack()


class Example(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("НЕГДЗ")

        ttk.Style().configure("TButton", padding = (0, 5, 0, 5), font = "sefif 10")

        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)

        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(3, pad=3)
    


        meh=ttk.Button(self, text="Квантовая физика", command=mehnew)
        meh.grid(row=1, column=1,)
        din=ttk.Button(self, text="Термодинамика")
        din.grid(row=2, column=1)
        sta=ttk.Button(self, text="СТО")
        sta.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I need this part of code("def mehnew()") to update the window

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by creating separate `Frame` widgets to contain each "window". Everything will be presented on the same `root` window, so you can (for example) use a `Button` to toggle through the different `Frame`s by hiding/showing the appropriate `Frame` as desired.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('300x300')

        self.btn_toggle = ttk.Button(
            self,
            text='Change Frames',
            command=self.switch_frames
        )
        self.btn_toggle.pack()
        # I'm using LabelFrames here so you can see when the change happens
        self.frame_a = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Alpha')
        ...
        # add widgets to this frame here
        ...
        # pack this frame to make it visible by default
        self.frame_a.pack(expand=True, fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.frame_b = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Beta')
        ...
        # add widgets to this frame here
        ...

        self.current_frame = 0  # the currently shown frame
        # keep a list (tuple) of all your frames
        self.frames = (self.frame_a, self.frame_b)
        
    def switch_frames(self):
        # hide the currently visible frame
        self.frames[self.current_frame].pack_forget()
        # set the index of the next frame to be shown
        # we only have two, so this is just an example
        if self.current_frame == 0:
            self.current_frame = 1
        elif self.current_frame == 1:
            self.current_frame = 0
        # show the new frame
        self.frames[self.current_frame].pack(expand=True, fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)


if __name__ == '__main__':  # start the app
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```